# Can someone show me step by step how to handle this convergence problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just took my final and one of the questions read:

> Use the integral test to determine the convergence or divergence of the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^n}{1+e^{2n}}.$$

I struggled with using the integral test when we covered it, would someone mind walking me through it?

Comment: In the denominator of your fraction,  do you mean $e^{2n}$, or $(e^2) \cdot n$?

Comment: The first one, my apologies that it doesn't look like that. Fixed it now.

Comment: Not to disregard examiner, but I wonder why they ask to use Integral test when this can be handled most simply by a comparison with geometric series. Clearly $a_{n} < e^{-n} = (1/e)^{n}$ and since $0 < 1/e < 1$ it follows that $a_{n}$ is convergent. I believe tests of convergence should be used in the order of their simplicity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I believe it was solely to show that we understand the integral test. There were numerous other ones that dealt with other tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral test says that if $f$ is some decreasing function $\mathbb{R}^+ \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges if and only if the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

Therefore, to check if your sum converges, we need to know whether the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}} dx$ converges. By the substitution $u=e^x$, $$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}} dx = \int_{x=1}^\infty \frac1{1+u^2} du = \tan^{-1}(e^x) \big|_{x=1}^\infty = \frac\pi2 - \tan^{-1}(e).$$

The exact value of this integral isn't very important for our purposes, however. All we care about is that it converges, so the series does to.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Good idea. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't look too bad at all. I wish I had read it once over prior to the final. Nonetheless, I'm glad I know it now! Thank you for your help

Comment: Just by curiosity, I computed the sum : it has a closed form which involves the QPolygamma function (which gives the successive derivatives of the q-digamma function). I even never heard about the existence of such a strange function. The limit of the sum is (4.21271 - Pi) / 2 = 0.535561.